# Query taking too much time (around 5 minutes) in a DB with over 5.000.000 entries

Tags: laravel-5

I'm doing a query like this:

```
$data = TopFiber::select(DB::raw('UserName, sum(AcctInputOctets) as Input , sum(AcctOutputOctets) as Output'))
        ->where('AcctStartTime' , 'LIKE', $data['date'] . '%')->groupBy('UserName')->orderBy('Output', 'desc')->limit(20)->get();
```

And it's taking too much time! How do i simplify that to make it work faster?
If it can be simplified to seconds i'm really happy 
But anything around 1 minute is fine!

Comment: because you using string search not index key

Comment: how do i use index key instead ?

Comment: you can make any column as index key which you want just alter it and make it as index key

Comment: if i do that my table will stay the same?
Or can i experience errors with another applications running with that table?

Comment: nothing gona happen to your application with that

Comment: Ok, i'll try that
Thank you :3

Comment: @GauravGupta I added an index to AcctStartTime but it still taking like 5 mins to complete the query :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Create Index to AcctStartTime
2- Add Date Range Picker instead of Single Date Picker
3- Be Happy!